# SQLAlchemy initialize_db.py - Having trouble with the initial data fill syntax

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have the following tables:

```
 Schema |      Name      | Type  |  Owner
--------+----------------+-------+---------
 public | fds_funds      | table | finance
 public | fdt_fund_types | table | finance
 public | usf_user_funds | table | finance
 public | usr_users      | table | finance
```

I'm trying to initialize some data in a couple of my databases. Basically I'm trying to add a "cash" fund_type, and then add a fund using that fund_type. The issue, of course, is that I don't know the ID of the fund_type until it's in the database, and I don't want to hardcode it.

So my initializedb.py currently looks like this:

```
def main(argv=sys.argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        usage(argv)
    config_uri = argv[1]
    options = parse_vars(argv[2:])
    setup_logging(config_uri)
    settings = get_appsettings(config_uri, options=options)
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    with transaction.manager:
        fund_type = FundType(fdt_type_name='cash')
        DBSession.add(fund_type)
        transaction.commit()

    with transaction.manager:
        fund = Fund(fds_name='Vanguard Prime Money Market Fund', fds_symbol='vmmxx', fds_fdt_fund_type_id=fund_type.fdt_fund_type_id)
        DBSession.add(fund)
        transaction.commit()
```

So when I run the initialize script, I'm getting the following out put:

```
2014-07-29 19:05:09,011 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][MainThread] {}
2014-07-29 19:05:09,014 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][MainThread] COMMIT
2014-07-29 19:05:09,022 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][MainThread] BEGIN (implicit)
2014-07-29 19:05:09,024 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][MainThread] INSERT INTO fdt_fund_types (fdt_type_name, fdt_usr_user_id) VALUES (%(fdt_type_name)s, %(fdt_usr_user_id)s) RETURNING fdt_fund_types.fdt_fund_type_id
2014-07-29 19:05:09,024 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][MainThread] {'fdt_type_name': 'cash', 'fdt_usr_user_id': None}
2014-07-29 19:05:09,025 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][MainThread] COMMIT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/bin/initialize_corefinance_db", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('corefinance==0.0', 'console_scripts', 'initialize_corefinance_db')()
  File "/var/www/finance/corefinance/corefinance/scripts/initializedb.py", line 45, in main
    fund = Fund(fds_name='Vanguard Prime Money Market Fund', fds_symbol='vmmxx', fds_fdt_fund_type_id=fund_type.fdt_fund_type_id)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.5-py3.2-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 233, in __get__
    return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), dict_)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.5-py3.2-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 577, in get
    value = callable_(state, passive)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.5-py3.2-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 422, in __call__
    self.manager.deferred_scalar_loader(self, toload)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.5-py3.2-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 563, in load_scalar_attributes
    (state_str(state)))
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <FundType at 0x3b5b150> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed
```

My issue is that I'm fairly new to pyramid, so I'm not quite sure what the proper syntax is or whether I'm even supposed to do this in this place. I can't seem to find any examples, and I'm not sure what "not bound to a session" means.

Answer (score 0):

After more reading and fiddling, I finally got it to work.

It turns out that pyramid doesn't use the explicit commit statement, as it uses a transaction manager.

All that is needed is a flush statement to populate the ID field..

```
def main(argv=sys.argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        usage(argv)
    config_uri = argv[1]
    options = parse_vars(argv[2:])
    setup_logging(config_uri)
    settings = get_appsettings(config_uri, options=options)
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    with transaction.manager:
        fund_type = FundType(fdt_type_name='cash')
        DBSession.add(fund_type)
        DBSession.flush()

        fund = Fund(fds_name='Vanguard Prime Money Market Fund', fds_symbol='vmmxx', fds_fdt_fund_type_id=fund_type.fdt_fund_type_id)
        DBSession.add(fund)
```